# What is occuring for my if statement not to register?

Tags: java, statements

I am writing a program that allows the user to input the sides of a triangle and receive information about their triangle such as height, angle measurement, type of triangle, and area. For some reason my program won't register the if statements.

I have tried switching conditions and other various measures yet nothing works. If somebody could take a look I would appreciate it.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Mathey
{
    public double squareRoot(double n)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(n);
    }
    public double square(double n)
    {
        return Math.pow(n,2);
    }
    public double sin(double n)
    {
        return Math.sin(n);
    }
    public double arcCos(double n)
    {
        return Math.acos(n);
    }
    public double round(double n)
    {
        return Math.round(n);
    }
    public double degrees (double n)
    {
        return Math.toDegrees(n);
    }
    public double radians (double n)
    {
        return Math.toRadians(n);
    }
}
```

Here is the triangle class:

```
public class TriangleCrazy {
    private int a, b, c;
    private double h, alpha2, beta2, gamma2;

    int type;
    Mathey mathStuff = new Mathey();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public TriangleCrazy(int a2, int b2, int c2) {
        a = a2;
        b = b2;
        c = c2;
    }

    public void triTest() {
        int flag = 1;

        while (flag == 1) {
            if (a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b) {
                System.out.println("You have enetered a proper triangle");
                flag = 0;
            } else if (a + b <= c || b + c <= a || a + c <= b) {
                System.out.println("Sorry you did not enter a proper triangle please try again");
                System.out.print("Please enter the sides of your triangle (A B C) ");
                int a = reader.nextInt();
                int b = reader.nextInt();
                int c = reader.nextInt();
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
                this.c = c;

            }
        }
    }

    public void triType() {
        double test = mathStuff.square(a) + mathStuff.square(c);
        double cTest = mathStuff.square(c);
        int type;

        if (test == cTest) {
            type = 1;
            this.type = type;
        } else if (test > cTest) {
            type = 2;
            this.type = type;
        } else if (test < cTest) {
            type = 3;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void angleFinder() {


        double a2 = mathStuff.square(a);
        double b2 = mathStuff.square(b);
        double c2 = mathStuff.square(c);
        double pi = 3.14159265359;
        double total = 180;

        double cosA = ((a2 + c2 - b2) / (2 * a * c));
        ;
        double cosB = ((a2 + b2 - c2) / (2 * a * b));
        double cosC = ((b2 + c2) - a2) / ((2 * b) * c);

        double arcCosA = mathStuff.arcCos(cosA);
        double arcCosB = mathStuff.arcCos(cosB);
        double arcCosC = mathStuff.arcCos(cosC);

        double alpha = mathStuff.degrees(arcCosA);
        double beta = mathStuff.degrees(arcCosB);
        double gamma = mathStuff.degrees(arcCosC);

        double alpha2 = mathStuff.round(alpha);
        double beta2 = mathStuff.round(beta);
        double gamma2 = mathStuff.round(gamma);

        this.alpha2 = alpha2;
        this.beta2 = beta2;
        this.gamma2 = gamma2;

        System.out.println("The measurement of the angles for your triangle is " + alpha2 + " " + beta2 + " " + gamma2);
    }

    public void heronForm() {
        double sideTotal = .5 * (a + b + c);
        double next = ((sideTotal) * (sideTotal - a) * (sideTotal - b) / (sideTotal - c));
        double area = mathStuff.squareRoot(next);

        System.out.println("The program will now calculate the area using Heron's Formula: ");

        System.out.println("s=(.5 * " + a + "+" + b + "+" + c + ")");
        System.out.println("The square root of s(s-" + a + ")(s-" + b + ")(s-" + c + ") = area");
        System.out.println("The area is " + area);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void height() {
        double h = c * mathStuff.sin(alpha2);
        h = mathStuff.round(h);
        this.h = h;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return h;
    }
}
```

Here is my driver:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the sides of your triangle from smallest to largest (A B C): ");

        int a = reader.nextInt();
        int b = reader.nextInt();
        int c = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println();
        TriangleCrazy tri = new TriangleCrazy(a, b, c);
        tri.triTest();
        System.out.println();
        tri.triType();
        int type2 = tri.getType();
        if (type2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("The triangle is an Right Triangle");
        } else if (type2 == 2) {
            System.out.println("The triangle is an Acute Triangle");
        } else if (type2 == 3) {
            System.out.println("The triangle is an Obtuse Triangle");
        }

        System.out.println();
        tri.angleFinder();
        System.out.println();
        tri.heronForm();
        System.out.println();
        tri.height();
        if (type2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("The height of your triangle is " + a);
        } else if (type2 == 2) {
            double h = tri.getHeight();
            System.out.println("The height of your triangle is " + h);
        } else if (type2 == 3) {
            double h = tri.getHeight();
            System.out.println("The height of your triangle is " + h);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output so you know what I am talking about.

Please enter the sides of your triangle from smallest to largest (A B C): 3 4 5

You have enetered a proper triangle

The triangle is an Acute Triangle

The measurement of the angles for your triangle is 53.0 90.0 37.0

The program will now calculate the area using Heron's Formula: 
s=(.5 * 3+4+5)
The square root of s(s-3)(s-4)(s-5) = area
The area is 6.0

The height of your triangle is 2.0

As you can see, it ignores the if statements I created in order to find the type of triangle. I have no idea why this is.

I had to create them in order to know if the height was to be found using the formula or was one of the sides in a right triangle. The height in a right triangle is as you know the smallest side.

If anybody could take a look and help me fine the bug I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the member `type` has value of `0`. In function `triType` you shadow the member `type` with a local variable `type`. Since the members are initialized to the appropriate zeroes, `getType` returns 0.

Comment: Define "shadowed" as in I shoud remove the private int type or do something to variable type in the function. I am confused because I redeclare the variable to a different value in the statment.

Comment: Shadowing is a term describing using two variables with the same name in two different contexts. In this case there is a local variable `type` in the function and a member variable `type` in the class. When you change the value of something named `type` you refer to the "closest" one - the local variable. The member variable is left unchanged. If you want to refer to the class variable use `this.type` or remove the local variable.

Comment: Okay I went back and added the this.type=type in teach of the if statments in triType() as well as fixed my stamtents in the driver. Now it reads the data however it registers 3,4,5 as an Acute triangle when my math is clearly correct. Here is the new output

Comment: Please enter the sides of your triangle from smallest to largest (A B C): 3 4 5

You have enetered a proper triangle

The triangle is an Acute Triangle

The measurement of the angles for your triangle is 53.0 90.0 37.0

The program will now calculate the area using Heron's Formula: 
s=(.5 * 3+4+5)
The square root of s(s-3)(s-4)(s-5) = area
The area is 6.0


The height of your triangle is 2.0

Comment: Could you please edit your original question to take the changes you've already made into account? It seems like a floating-point error, but I can't reproduce it.